# efficiency of utilizing dll in c source code

Tags: c, dll

I have a dll which I'd like to use in a `c` program,

- Do you think is efficient to have a dll (lots of common functions) and then create a program that will eventually use them, or have all the source code?
- To include the dll, What syntax must be followed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you think is efficient to have a dll (lots of common functions) and then create a program that will eventually use them,or have all the source code.

For memory and disk space, it is more efficient to use a shared library (a DLL is the Windows implementation of shared libraries), assuming that at least two programs use this component. If only one program will ever use this component, then there is no memory or disk space savings to be had.

Shared libraries can be slightly slower than statically linking the code; however, this is likely to be incredibly minor, and shared libraries carry a number of benefits that make it more than worthwhile (such as the ability to load and handle symbols dynamically, which allows for plugin-like architectures). That said, there are also some disadvantages (if you are not careful about where your DLLs live, how they are versioned, and who can update them, then you can get into [DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell)).

> To include the dll, What syntax must be followed?

This depends. There are two ways that shared libraries can be used. In the first way, you tell the linker to reference the shared library, and the shared library will automatically be loaded on program startup, and you would basically reference the code like normal (include the various headers and just use the name of the symbol when you want to reference it). The second way is to dynamically load the shared library (on Windows this is done via [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) while it is done on UNIX with [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)). This second way makes it possible to change the behavior of the program based on the presence or absence of symbols in the shared library and to inspect the available set of symbols. For the second way, you would use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows) or [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) (UNIX) to obtain a pointer to a function defined in the library, and you would pass around function pointers to reference the functions that were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your functions into either a static library ( a .lib) which is merged into your application at compile time and is basically the same as putting the .c files in the project.

Or you can use a dll where the functions are included at run time. the advantage of a dll is that two programs which use the same functions can use the same dll (saving disk space) and you can upgrade the dll without changing the program - neither of these probably matters for you.

The dll is automatically loaded when your program runs there is nothing special you need to do to include it ( you can load a dll specifically in your code - there are sometimes special reasons to do this)

Edit - if you need to create a stub lib for an existing dll see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313

Comment: right now I am using dev shed c/c++, do you know an example code?

Comment: @darkcminor, you call it like you normally would. You include the ".h" file with the declaration, and then you simply use the function. You would need to change the project configuration to link against the DLL.

Comment: The dll will come with a header defining the functions and a stub lib - simply include the header and link the .lib. Sorry don't knwo the dev shed gui